# my request failed when the post 'content-type' is application/x-www-form-urlencoded and * form field param= { <this is a json object>}

Tags: karate

The request is failed when I post request an API whose header content-type is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' and post body is ' param = { this is a json object} '

The curl request like this, it works.

curl 'http://localhost:7272/Acme/iEhr/PersonSample' -H 'Cookie: ACMETMP=fe35925f-a243-4be9-8e73-60c461ef9bd3; JSESSIONID=47A43F4988F232CC7B53F6CF30B954F6; SESSION=e580c2c7-bf4b-45e6-93fc-de6f79854346' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:7272' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:7272/route/sampleadd' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'param=%7B%22cityid%22%3A%222091afc3-bcd6-46d9-8033-3548ad10933b%22%2C%22areaid%22%3A%222d09f5e5-a07d-445c-9d8a-51eb436699a8%22%2C%22hosid%22%3A%220f226b63-58ad-44d7-bf23-25d0345276e1%22%2C%22deptid%22%3A%2291c176f5-63ca-4b95-87c4-9f311864ff9b%22%2C%22barcode%22%3A%221000000000%22%2C ......' --compressed

it also works with postman request but failed with Karate

```
Scenario: 样本登记

    Given path 'iEhr/PersonSample'
    And header Content-type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'

    * cookies { JSESSIONID: '#(jsessionID)',SESSION: '#(sessionID)', ACMETMP: '#(acmetmpID)'}

    And form fields param = {"cityid":"2091afc3-bcd6-46d9-8033-3548ad10933b","areaid":"2d09f5e5-a07d-445c-9d8a-51eb436699a8","hosid":"0f226b63-58ad-44d7-bf23-25d0345276e1","deptid":"91c176f5-63ca-4b95-87c4-9f311864ff9b","barcode":"1000000000","mothername":"manual-mother1","pregweek":"21", and so on}

    When method post
    Then status 200
    * print response
```

'And form fields param = {this is a json object}'

this sentence should work but failed for us.

**What is my means by karate failed ?**
The response code is different compared with Karate, and it is expected result when working with postman.

**Postman**

[the necessary param data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Qys.png)

**Karate**:

```
18:14:09.437 request:
1 > POST http://localhost:7272/Acme/iEhr/PersonSample
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Length: 899
1 > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
1 > Cookie: ACMETMP=d22c0d9a-b98b-4f6f-9e42-2f9bdffa22c8; JSESSIONID=09268B9F4CA0C15AE3FFB1A26BE424ED; SESSION=2baafdac-38d6-43d0-ac5c-d39e2b29fa48
1 > Host: localhost:7272
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_211)
cityid=2091afc3-bcd6-46d9-8033-3548ad10933b&areaid=2d09f5e5-a07d-445c-9d8a-51eb436699a8&hosid=0f226b63-58ad-44d7-bf23-25d0345276e1&deptid=91c176f5-63ca-4b95-87c4-9f311864ff9b&barcode=1000000000&mothername=manual-mother1&pregweek=21&pregday=1&midentitycard=&birthday=2018-10-01+00%3A00&collectdate=2019-05-15+14%3A38&personsex=1&personweight=4000&address=manual-testaddress1&mobile=15397006044&collectperson=&samplequality=1&borntype=1&linkman=&fidentitycard=&labitem=PHE&sampletype=1&btn=&isfee=0&personremark=&telephone=&bednumber=&labstring=&collectnumber=&freecode=&dhosid=0f226b63-58ad-44d7-bf23-25d0345276e1&reviewtype=&diagnosticstatus=&centerid=bb717701-10de-47ee-b49e-693261c6df22&nowdeptid=07eeec75-079b-4fa9-93cf-c45ddc9a87b9&operator=%E9%BB%84%E5%86%88%E5%B8%82%E5%A6%87%E5%B9%BC%E4%BF%9D%E5%81%A5%E9%99%A2&labitems=PHE&pagecode=sampleadd&modifydetail=%E6%A0%B7%E6%9C%AC%E5%BD%95%E5%85%A5

18:14:09.557 response time in milliseconds: 120.12
1 < 200
1 < Accept-Charset: big5, big5-hkscs, cesu-8, euc-jp, euc-kr, gb18030, gb2312, gbk, ibm-thai ...... and so on
1 < Content-Length: 52
1 < Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
1 < Date: Wed, 15 May 2019 10:14:09 GMT
1 < X-Application-Context: Acme.jc.test:dev:7272
[{"code":-90018,"result":"(错误-90018)失败！"}]
```

Comment: if you are sending json then content-type header needs to be `application/json`

Comment: what do you mean by failed in karate? can you please mention exact failure logs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have re-edited my question in the below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
And form field param = {"cityid":"2091afc3-bcd6-46d9-8033-3548ad10933b","areaid":"2d09f5e5-a07d-445c-9d8a-51eb436699a8","hosid":"0f226b63-58ad-44d7-bf23-25d0345276e1","deptid":"91c176f5-63ca-4b95-87c4-9f311864ff9b","barcode":"1000000000","mothername":"manual-mother1","pregweek":"21","pregday":"1","midentitycard":"","birthday":"2018-10-01 00:00" ...... and so on }
```

I changed to this, it works now. 
I am misled by the keyword 'param' in karate and the keyword 'param' used by our product code.

Comment: my bad I didn't notice you were using `form fields` instead of `form field` for single value. but i wonder how my answer didn't work as I have used `form fields` with `param` as a key in the JSON provided.. Anyways it worked, cool!.. Please mark your answer as accepted after some time.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
Scenario: 样本登记 
 Given path 'iEhr/PersonSample' 
 * cookies { JSESSIONID: '#(jsessionID)',SESSION: '#(sessionID)', ACMETMP: '#(acmetmpID)'} 
 And def ffParams = {"param" : {"cityid":"2091afc3-bcd6-46d9-8033-3548ad10933b","areaid":"2d09f5e5-a07d-445c-9d8a-51eb436699a8","hosid":"0f226b63-58ad-44d7-bf23-25d0345276e1","deptid":"91c176f5-63ca-4b95-87c4-9f311864ff9b","barcode":"1000000000","mothername":"manual-mother1","pregweek":"21"}} 
 And form fields ffParams
 When method post 
 Then status 200 
 * print response
```

Form fields are by default url-encoded only no need to explicitly mention it in header

Comment: many thanks for your reply, however, it doesn't work for us. 'param' is a necessary field in the APIs, logs of APIs are written like this within our product code. I have re-edited my question in the below.